# How to use Pandas merge all columns' value into one column, and header names become a new column's field value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

| Test A | Test B | Test C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 45 | 24 |
| 56 | 62 | 52 |
| 73 | 68 | 11 |
| 13 | 34 | 96 |

And I would like transform to:

| Test Name | Result |
| --- | --- |
| Test A | 22 |
| Test A | 56 |
| Test A | 73 |
| Test A | 13 |
| Test B | 45 |
| Test B | 62 |
| Test B | 68 |
| Test B | 34 |
| Test C | 24 |
| Test C | 52 |
| Test C | 11 |
| Test C | 96 |

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) :

```
out = df.melt(var_name="Test Name", value_name="Result")
```

##### # Output :

```
print(out)

   Test Name  Result
0     Test A      22
1     Test A      56
2     Test A      73
3     Test A      13
4     Test B      45
..       ...     ...
7     Test B      34
8     Test C      24
9     Test C      52
10    Test C      11
11    Test C      96

[12 rows x 2 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I just can't goolge this method. You can see that my topic(qustion)'s title is not even well defined. My English is not good enough I guess. Do you mind teach me how to google this question? I mean, in this case, what sentence you will use to google this question?

Comment: Hey man, you're welcome. Actually, most of the time, regarding standard data transformation you don't have to google it since pandas has a really good documentation. For example, about reshaping dataframes, there is a big chapter talking about that (including `pandas.melt`) with visualisations. Take a look and good luck ;) : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html